# Django tutorial 1 issue

Tags: python, django

I have been stuck on this problem for 3 days, trying different things to solve the problem but no avail.. It's been wrecking my head and I hope someone here can help me..

Basically I'm doing the tutorial for Django and in part 1, you are meant to print the output of Question from the models.py file in the polls project.However I am not getting the desired output despite modifying my code accordingly to the tutorial.

here is the code for the models.py file within the polls project
    import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

```
 class Question(models.Model):
     question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

 def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text
 def was_published_recently(self):
         return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() -datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
     choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
       return self.choice_text
```

The output I should be receiving when running the python shell from terminal is

```
   [<Question: "what's up?">]
```

However I am receiving:

```
 [<Question: Question object>]
```

Please help!

Comment: Are you using Python3 or Python2?

Answer (score 2):

Fix the indentation of the code, the methods are not part of your classes.

```
class Question(models.Model):
     question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

     def __unicode__(self):
            return self.question_text

     def was_published_recently(self):
             return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() -datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
           return self.choice_text
```

Comment: In the actual file the methods are at the leftmost of the page aligned with class so it's not an indentation issue...i only did the indentation here to make it fit into the code block

Comment: so try to change to __str__ instead __unicode__, maybe it is a problem with your python version

Comment: I'm running 2.7.6 which requires unicode.. str is for 3 and above i believe..atleast thats what the tutorial says

Comment: @HassanAli if the methods are aligned at the left, that is *wrong*. They need to be indented one level to the right, as Yuri shows.